# Injecting JSX into a React Native Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

How can JSX be injected *(and rendered)* dynamically into a React Native component?

For example, an ajax call returns:

```
<View style={{ width: 75 }}>
    <Button
        onPress={ makeSecondRequest }
        title="Inserted (Ajax) Button" />
</View>
```

Assuming this function was also injected:

```
makeSecondRequest() {
    anotherAjaxCall()
}
```

The purpose is for creating dynamic, user-generated layouts that can render natively *(and responsively)* in React Native. Any guidance on direction would be appreciated as well. Cheers!

Comment: Apart from your worthwhile question - is not "injecting view" solution considered an anti-pattern? (rendering dynamically from API endpoint)

Comment: i agree, it doesn't feel right, but I haven't yet thought of a better approach to dynamic layouts. in other words, dynamic "components" at runtime.